# playwright python SSL peer certificate or SSH remote key was not OK

Tags: python, playwright, playwright-python

I get this error when trying to run:

```
import asyncio
from playwright.async_api import async_playwright, Playwright

async def run(playwright: Playwright):
    webkit = playwright.webkit
    browser = await webkit.launch(headless=False)
    context = await browser.new_context(ignore_https_errors=True)
    page = await context.new_page()
    await page.goto("http://minha.anem.dz/pre_inscription")
    
    await browser.close()

async def main():
    async with async_playwright() as playwright:
        await run(playwright)
asyncio.run(main())
```

error :

```
playwright._impl._errors.Error: SSL peer certificate or SSH remote key was not OK
```

I have solution if you need.

Comment: "i have soulition if you need" -- why not post it as a [self answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)? [Related GH issue in Node Playwright](https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/600)

Answer (score 0):

Add `ignore_https_errors=True` to your code like this:

```
import asyncio
from playwright.async_api import async_playwright, Playwright

async def run(playwright: Playwright):
    webkit = playwright.webkit
    browser = await webkit.launch(headless=False)
    context = await browser.new_context(ignore_https_errors=True)
    page = await context.new_page()
    await page.goto("http://example.com")
    
    await browser.close()

async def main():
    async with async_playwright() as playwright:
        await run(playwright)
asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: You already have `ignore_https_errors=True` in your question code... I suggest removing "I have the solution if you need" and the fix from the question, if your goal is to create a self-answer.